# Asserting on catch block code inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, try-catch, sinon, sinon-chai

I am hard time writing test to assert something happened inside catch block which is executed inside `forEach` loop.

**Prod code**

```
function doSomething(givenResourceMap) {
  givenResourceMap.forEach(async (resourceUrl) => {
    try {
        await axios.delete(resourceUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Error on deleting resource ${resourceUrl}`);
        logger.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
});
```

I am wanting to assert `logger.error` is being called twice and called with right arguments each time. So I wrote some test like this

```
describe('Do Something', () => {
  it('should log message if fail to delete the resource', function() {        
    const resource1Url = chance.url();
    const givenResourceMap = new Map();
    const thrownError = new Error('Failed to delete');
    givenResourceMap.set(resource1Url);

    sinon.stub(logger, 'error');
    sinon.stub(axios, 'delete').withArgs(resource1Url).rejects(thrownError);

    await doSomething(givenResourceMap);

    expect(logger.error).to.have.callCount(2);
    expect(logger.error.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal(`Error deleting resource ${resource1Url}`);
    expect(logger.error.getCall(1).args[0]).to.equal(thrownError);
    // Also need to know how to assert about `throw error;` line
  });
});
```

I am using Mocha, sinon-chai, expect tests. Above test is failing saying `logger.error` is being 0 times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `await` on a function that doesn't return a `Promise`.  Note that `doSomething` is not `async` and does not return a `Promise` object.

The `forEach` function is `async` but that means they'll return right away with an unresolved `Promise` and you don't ever `await` on them.

In reality, `doSomething` will return before the work inside of the `forEach` is complete, which is probably not what you intended.  To do that you could use a regular for-loop like this:

```
async function doSomething(givenResourceMap) {
  for (const resourceUrl of givenResourceMap) {
    try {
        await axios.delete(resourceUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Error on deleting resource ${resourceUrl}`);
        logger.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that it changes the return type of `doSomething` to be a `Promise` object rather than just returning `undefined` as it originally did.  But it does let you do an `await` on it as you want to in the test (and presumably in production code also).

However since you re-throw the exception caught in the loop, your test will exit abnormally.  The test code would have to also change to catch the expected error:

```
it('should log message if fail to delete the resource', function(done) { 
  // ... the setup stuff you had before...       
  await doSomething(givenResourceMap).catch(err => {
    expect(logger.error).to.have.callCount(2);
    expect(logger.error.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal(`Error deleting resource ${resource1Url}`);
    expect(logger.error.getCall(1).args[0]).to.equal(thrownError);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Test is passing even wihtout having logger.error statements in the prod code. I tried with async/await in test instead of done too.

Comment: you will need your expects to be in the `catch` since you do `throw` an exception on the error. The `done` may not be mandatory but it won't hurt. What problem are you having now?  if the tests pass, you're happy right?